# apache.commons.cli and "long" command-line parameters in Java

Tags: java, bash, command-line-arguments

Is it possible to use 'long' parameters for command-line options with apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser in java? 'Long' I mean not a single word, but a sentence in block-quotes ('"'). Java application is being started from bash-script file.

Script file:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp <classpath> MyClass $@
```

Call (which returns only "long" for '-p' argument and "another" for '-r' argument):

```
./script.sh -p "long parameter" -r "another long parameter"
```

Now I can only do something like this to get "long parameter" string:

```
./script.sh -p "long" -p "parameter"
```

Of course I can add '-p' programmatically as many times as needed, but this prevents me from using '-' sign in parameter values, as I need to track other command-line switches. Besides this seems to be far not correct approach.

CommandLine options are created like this:

```
org.apache.commons.cli.Options options = new Options();
options.addOption(Option.builder("p").longOpt("param").hasArg().desc("parameter description").build());
```

And then parsed like this:

```
CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
CommandLine         line = parser.parse( options, args );
if (line.hasOption('p')) params = line.getOptionValues("param");
```

Comment: `longOpt` refers to the _name_ of the option, not the length of the option value.  Whether or not a long string is passed to your code depends on the shell involved.  What OS and shell are you using?

Comment: I'm doing this on MacOSX in Bash shell

Comment: Which shell are you using, and does it use double quotes to surround strings?

Comment: I use bash and for parameter values I use double quotes to surround strings (as I've wrote it in question), literally: # java ClassName -p "value1 value2 value3"

Comment: If you want to see what CLI is receiving, just do `System.out.println(args);` where `args` is the argument to your `main` method.  This will tell you if the shell is passing the quoted strings correctly.  Add the output from that to your question.

Comment: Actually I did this during debugging and what is strange, is that for command-line argument in double quotes (i.e. "some argument"), when I output the values of args array I'm getting 2 values: "some", "argument" instead of one "some argument"

Comment: Is the Java code being invoked from a shell script or directly on the command line?  What happens if you use single quotes instead?

Comment: Just found the problem... i'm invoking java class from shell script passing all the arguments via $@ - that's the problem. Calling the class directly solves the problem. Thank you, Jim.

Comment: Quoting in bash is hard to get right...:-\  I suggest you write up the solution as an answer and then accept after the required delay. The question will be useful to someone else in the future.

Comment: wrapping $@ in script into double quotes solves the problem: "$@"

Comment: Please edit your question to include the fact that you're using a shell script, then use the ANSWER box (not a comment) to explain the solution.  The primary purpose of StackOverflow is to help OTHER people in the future.  Solving your problem is secondary, so it is very helpful to post an answer and then accept. This lets future readers know that the answer was a good solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it's got clear (thanks to Jim Garrison) that the problem is caused by calling java class from bash-script (passing all the arguments with $@). Wrapping $@ into double quotes in script solved the problem. Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp <path> MyClass "$@"
```

instead of incorrect

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp <path> MyClass $@
```